# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm getting the above error on an archive page on WP when trying to load certain posts. Others are working just as expected.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 var linki = $('*[data-target="#post970"]') ;
 var urli =linki.attr('data-url');
 var finalurli = urli.substring(urli.indexOf("/blog/")+5);
 console.log(finalurli);
 window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/blog"+finalurli);
 var post_id= "post970" ;
 $("#"+post_id).modal();
});
```

Comment: check the value of `urli` by `console.log(urli)`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: urli is not defined

Comment: after this line `var urli =linki.attr('data-url');`

Comment: Without your HTML we cannot know what is happening. The first thing I can see is that your `data-target="#post970"` element has no `data-url` attribute, so you are receiving an undefined value, but we cannot see why is this happening.

By the way, if you are going to program, you should learn to debug. If it says that `urli` is undefined, then you know that this line is the one failing `var finalurli = urli.substring(urli.indexOf("/blog/")+5);`, so you must see WHY is `urli` undefined. And the first thing to look at is where it gets its undefined value.